# firebaseコマンドのバージョンを上げる方法を教えてください

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

#### 【質問の主旨】

Firebaseでウェブサイトを公開するためにfirebaseコマンドのバージョンを上げる方法を教えてください。

#### 【質問の補足】

【質問の主旨】について5点補足説明をします。

1.

今回の質問に関わる環境のバージョンは以下のとおりです。

```
$ node -v
v8.11.3
$ npm -v
6.9.0
$ firebase -V
4.0.2
$ anyenv version
ndenv: v8.11.3 (set by /Users/MYUSERNAME/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/version)
rbenv: system (set by /Users/MYUSERNAME/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/version)
```

2.

上記の環境で`$ firebase deploy`を実行するとfirebaseのバージョンを4.1.0以上にするように指摘を受けました。

```
$ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'jissen-pwa'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...

Error: HTTP Error: 410, This version of the Firebase CLI is no longer able to deploy to Firebase Hosting. Please upgrade to a newer version (>= 4.1.0). If you have further questions, please reach out to Firebase support.
fukuiyou-no-MBP:jissen-pwa-project MYUSERNAME$ firebase -V
4.0.2
```

3.

firebaseにログインすることが久しぶりだったので、`$ firebase deploy`を実行する前に、firebaseに再ログインしました。

```
$ firebase login --reauth

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Update available: 6.6.0 (current: 4.0.2)     │
│ Run npm install -g firebase-tools to update. │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────┘

? Allow Firebase to collect anonymous CLI usage and error reporting information?
 Yes
```

4.

`$ firebase login --reauth`したときにバージョンアップのためのコマンドが表示されたので、`$ sudo npm install -g firebase-tools`を実行しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ですが実行をすると、上記のようなエラー画像が表示されました。firebaseのバージョンを確認すると、従前通り4.0.2のままでした。

5.

下記の文字列はエラーの文章を一部引用したものです。

```
npm WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/MYUSERNAME/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/versions/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/.staging/firebase-tools-f6fc0e7d/lib/test/helpers'
npm WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/MYUSERNAME/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/versions/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/.staging/firebase-tools-f6fc0e7d/lib/test/hosting'
npm WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/MYUSERNAME/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/versions/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/.staging/firebase-tools-f6fc0e7d/lib/test/firest'
```

エラーの文言に`Users/MYUSERNAME/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/versions/v8.11.3...`という箇所がありますが、これは**anyenvやfirebase-toolsをインストール**したときの影響であると考えられます。そのインストールをしたときの様子は個人ブログでまとめています。

- [anyenvをインストールしたときに環境変数（$PATH）の設定を間違える。その修正方法について](https://e-yota.com/webservice/anyenv_pathvariable_error/)
- [firebase-toolsをインストールするために新しくanyenvのパスを通した件](https://e-yota.com/webservice/firebase-tools_install_anyenv/)

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

(sudo ではなく) を実行したら、うまくいきませんか？

---

#### 2018/04/20 （コメントを受けての追記)

おそらく、 anyenv で ndenv まわりをインストール・アップデートする際に、 sudo を利用してしまって、権限周りがおかしくなっているように思います。

自分であったならば、たとえば

```
sudo chown -R ユーザー名:グループ名 ~/.anyenv
```

などで、 `~/.anyenv` 以下の権限まわりを修正すると思います。

Comment: Yuki Inoueさん。
コメントありがとうございます。

`sudo`なしの`$ npm install -g firebase-tools`を実行すると「権限不足」を指摘されて、やはりfirbaeのバージョンをあげることができません。


```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/MYUSERNAE/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/versions/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/fast-url-parser
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/MYUSERNAE/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/versions/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/got
```

エラーの文字列を一部引用すると、こんな感じです。

Comment: @echizenya_yota 追記しました。

Comment: Yuki Inoueさん。コメントありがとうございます。`~/.anyenv`周りの権限を修正しました。また独自Google検索などで調べたコマンドを実行して試したところ、
現在、`$ firebase -V ndenv: firebase: command not found`という状態になりました。`command not found`に至るコマンドについて、https://hackmd.io/TWObpOw_SRiXC6AglSgmsA にまとめています。
また現在、コマンド画面で見えている画面については、http://takaiba.net/stackoverflow/stackoverflow20190420_1.png のURLで画面を貼っています。もし何かアドバイスをいただければ助かります。よろしくお願い申し上げます。